# Pass params to quarto as a separate file

Tags: quarto

**1.** params in file `index.qmd`.

````
---
title: '`r params$dataset`'
format: html
params:
  dataset: "iris"
---

This is the {{< meta params.dataset >}} dataset.

```{r,results="asis",echo=FALSE,comment=""}
cat(paste("This is the",params$dataset),"dataset")
```

```{r}
head(get(params$dataset))
```
````

`quarto render index.qmd`

This works as intended.

[image]

But, I want to move the params to a separate file and that doesn't work.

**2a.** params in `_metadata.yml`

params is moved to a separate file `_metadata.yml` which looks like this:

```
params:
  dataset: "iris"
```

`index.qmd` remains the same.

`quarto render index.qmd --execute-params _metadata.yml`

This fails with this error:

```
Error:
! object 'params' not found
Execution halted
```

**2b.** params in `_metadata.yml`

Same as above, but `_metadata.yml` looks like this (added `---`):

```
---
params:
  dataset: "iris"
---
```

`quarto render index.qmd --execute-params _metadata.yml`

Now, it's a different error.

```
ERROR: YAMLError: expected a single document in the stream, but found more 

YAMLError: expected a single document in the stream, but found more 
    at load (file:///opt/quarto/bin/quarto.js:11691:11)
```

**3a.** params in `_metadata.yml`

`metadata-files` is added to `index.qmd`

````
---
title: '`r params$dataset`'
format: html
metadata-files:
  - _metadata.yml
---

```{r,results="asis",echo=FALSE,comment=""}
cat(paste("This is the",params$dataset),"dataset")
```

```{r}
head(get(params$dataset))
```
````

`_metadata.yml` like this:

```
params:
  dataset: "iris"
```

`quarto render index.qmd`

```
Error:
! object 'params' not found
Execution halted
```

**3b.** params in `_metadata.yml`

Same as above, but `_metadata.yml` like this:

```
---
params:
  dataset: "iris"
---
```

`quarto render index.qmd`

```
Error reading metadata file from _metadata.yml

ERROR: YAMLException: expected a single document in the stream, but found more
YAMLException: expected a single document in the stream, but found more
```

`quarto 1.3.433`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the quarto developers for the solution. In addition to the params file, default params must be defined in the qmd. The params file must be in pure yaml. Metadata variables must be defined separately.

The example below works:

`index.qmd`

````
---
title: '`r params$dataset`'
format: html
params:
  dataset: "iris"
dataset: iris
---

This is the {{< meta dataset >}} dataset.

```{r,results="asis",echo=FALSE,comment=""}
cat(paste("This is the",params$dataset),"dataset")
```

```{r}
head(get(params$dataset))
```
````

`params.yml`

```
dataset: "mtcars"
```

`quarto render index.qmd --execute-params params.yml`

[image]